# How can I make an API that never been existed?

Tags: api, reversing

First, I want to make a program that has function playing music, next music .. etc..

and there are so many those kinds of program, so I just want to add some functions on it, but only thing that I have is, program, I tried to search API but there are not. SO...

Is is possible to make API on my own? and what kinds of skills do i need? for example reversing?